# Can't get CSS layer to rise above "opacitied" layer

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, z-index, opacity

Yeah, I know it's not a word, but my brain is on overdrive right now and it's near the end of my day.

Here's the codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mJKgwd

The HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail-bg">
        <a class="thumbnail client-blah1" href="#">
          <div class="client-title glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></div>
          <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="680px" height="510px" id="blah1-ph" class="img-responsive"></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail-bg">
        <a class="thumbnail client-blah1" href="#">
          <div class="client-title glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></div>
          <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="680px" height="510px" id="blah2-ph" class="img-responsive"></svg>
        </a>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail-bg">
        <a class="thumbnail client-blah1" href="#">
          <div class="client-title glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></div>
          <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="680px" height="510px" id="blah3-ph" class="img-responsive"></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail-bg">
        <a class="thumbnail client-blah1" href="#">
          <div class="client-title glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></div>
          <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="680px" height="510px" id="blah4-ph" class="img-responsive"></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-4 col-lg-3 thumb">
      <div class="thumbnail-bg">
        <a class="thumbnail client-blah1" href="#">
          <div class="client-title glyphicon glyphicon-zoom-in"></div>
          <svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.0" width="680px" height="510px" id="blah5-ph" class="img-responsive"></svg>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
.thumb {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-bg {
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1.0);
}
.thumbnail {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: opacity 1s ease;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
  opacity: 0.2;
}
.thumbnail:hover .client-title {
  display: block;
}
.client-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(34, 34, 34), 0 0 0 rgb(34, 34, 34), 1px 1px 8px rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .thumbnail {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}

.client-blah1 { background-image: url('https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=33&txt=300%C3%97300&w=300&h=300'); }
```

Everything works except for getting the overlaid glyphicon to show "above" the opacity layer on hover.

I've tried a number of different things including playing with z-index, physically moving the div element around the code (ie outside of the child element being set to low opacity to allow for the BG color to come through).

I'm not quite sure where to go with this from here, the code is an excerpt straight from the actual site code, so I know it's not environmental/other issues elsewhere in the codebase because the same thing happens in codepen.

I'm sure it's something simple and basic that I'm overlooking but I guess I can't see the forest from the trees, as they say.

Any help would be much appreciated, thanks in advance.

PS I don't want to just default to a jQuery based solution, the CSS is 99.9% there already.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use background color with rgba on the thumbnail class. So that the css only changes the opacity/alpha of the background not the whole container like opacity does.

```
.thumb {
    transform: translateZ(0);
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    position: relative;
}
.thumbnail-bg {
    background-color: rgba(34, 34, 34, 1.0);
}
.thumbnail {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 !important;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
    transition: background-color 1s ease;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
  background-color: rgba(99,99,99, 0.2)
}
.thumbnail:hover .client-title {
  display: block;
}
.client-title {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 5em;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgb(34, 34, 34), 0 0 0 rgb(34, 34, 34), 1px 1px 8px rgb(34, 34, 34);
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0;
    color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 992px) {
  .thumbnail {
    max-height: 200px;
  }
}

.client-blah1 { background-color: rgba(99,99,99,1) }
```

Comment: While this is incorrect, it did put me on the right path. I just wasn't coming at it from the right perspective.

Updated codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpKJoG

Comment: @GabrialMacLeod I agree. After I posted this I realized that now you don't have an image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution. Play around with it a bit:

```
.thumbnail {
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 0 !important;
    color: #ddd;
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
    max-height: 300px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.thumbnail:hover {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
       -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
            box-shadow: inset 0 0 1000px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Replace your `.thumbnail` and `.thumbnail:hover` CSS with the above and see what happens.

Your glyphicon-zoom-in item stays white, which is ideal.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was just going at it from the wrong direction.

Updated Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gpKJoG

```
fin
```